# Sitecore 9.1 authentication using OKTA

Tags: federated-authentication

I am trying to integrate OKTA authentication in Sitecore CD web site. I am able to redirect users in OKTA hosted URL and getting the Token in `AuthorizationCodeReceived` event. I am facing two issues in this event.

1. After calling the ClaimTransformation, it is redirecting me to the Sitecore error page `(/sitecore/service/error.aspx)` with the error message `Unsuccessful login with the external provider.` I debug my custom claim transformation class but it didn't throw any exception. Calling the below method for applying the transformation.

> AuthenticationTicket.Identity.ApplyClaimsTransformations(new
> TransformationContext(this.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration,
> IdentityProvider));

2. I have written my own custom user builder and made the below config entry.

   ```
    <mapEntry name="mysite" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"     resolve="true">
              <sites hint="list">
                <site>mysite</site>
                <site>website</site>            
              </sites> 
    <externalUserBuilder patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']" type="XXX.UserBuilder, myassembly" resolve="true">    
         <param desc="isPersistentUser">true</param>    
     </externalUserBuilder>
   ```

I have inherited the Userbuilder class from DefaultExternalUserBuilder class. This custom user builder is also not hitting and so unable to create virtual user.

Sitecore Version: 9.1 update 1
OKTA PKCE authentication

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Alok...

Comment: @gaurav, let me know if this blog "http://everydaysitecore.home.blog/2020/06/19/integrating-custom-identity-server-provider-into-sitecore-for-external-authentication-using-openid-connect/" I wrote sometime ago is of some help.

Comment: you need to show the config file with claimstransformation , to confirm if there is not issue in the claims section